# Joomla3 - how to display success notice after form submit (post handling)

Tags: php, forms, joomla3.0

I am coding a custom contact form and this form is a standard POST form.
The form looks something like this:

```
<form action="/path/to/my/phpfile.php" method="post" id="form">
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email"/>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
          <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Now, my PHP file looks something like this:

```
<?php
$email_from = $_POST['email']; 
$fromname = $_POST['name'];
$email_to = 'test@email.com';

$email_subject = 'Subject text....';
$email_message = 'Email message.....';

//Send the email
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

header('location: http://www.mywebsite.com/destination/');
?>
```

So, what I want to do is to display a success notice/message as a standard Joomla system message.

I have noticed that Joomla messages frontend are contained in this container in my template:

```
<div id="system-message-container">
<div id="system-message">
<div class="alert alert-notice"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
<h4 class="alert-heading">Header text...</h4>
<div>
        <p>Message....</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The question is, how do I create a code in the PHP file that transmits a system message to the destination page in Joomla?
I am using Joomla v. 3.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out how to tap in to the build in Joomla notification message system. It turned out to be very simple.

To display system messages you can simply use one of these lines:

```
//Standard message
JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($mymessage);

//Notice message
JError::raiseNotice(100, $mymessage);

//Warning message
JError::raiseWarning( 100, $mymessage );
```

So what i did in my case, was to send a URL variable e.g. ?message=success
and in my template file I simply made an if statement like this:

```
if($_GET["message"] == "success") {
            $displaymsg = "My message text..";
            JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($displaymsg);
}
```

I hope this helps others that are in the same situation I was in.

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you're sending the user to a location that is still within your Joomla! site, you can display a Joomla! system message and still get to do a redirect using Joomla's in-built redirection function i.e display the message when the user gets to the destination page. Like this:

```
  // give joomla the message to display...
  $app = JFactory::getApplication();
  $app->enqueueMessage('A message for the user');

  // ...and still do a redirect
  $app->redirect('http://www.myJoomlaSite.com/index.php?option=com_whatever');
```

So your user still gets your message on the destination page even after doing a redirect as long as the page is within your Joomla! site

Answer (score 0):

by default when user click on the submit bottom after submiting form joomla go to the  '/path/to/my/phpfile.php' direction. and when you echo some text in this direction ,this text sho to the user.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate a little what you mean?

Comment: when you want to submit a form in joomla it is very important to set action to form.if you want to create a component according to mvc you must set action look like this "index.php?option=com_componentname&view=viewname" .are you use MVC model??

Comment: No, this is a completely custom PHP-file only to handle this particular contact form. I was thinking/hoping it is possible to transmit the system message via an URL paramater maybe as "GET-data"

Comment: you can not use this on joomla .if you want to use that on joomla you must create a module or component or include it in template file.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me how I produce a system message in a template file? I guess I can make my own system message in the template file under specific condition, and then make a message that triggers when I pass a specific GET data in the URL..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third party extension, to display your php code as a module on an article. That way you can just program your own success notice.

Here is a list of extensions that does the job for you: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content

I would try and not use Jumi, it works, but in my case it created quite some errors.

Comment: Yes, I´m already using such a plugin /module for custom HTML,CSS, jQuery and PHP "Flexi Custom Code" but what I am after is to use the build-in Joomla message system and echo a message based on the response from an external post-script. What I specifically would really want is to be able to trigger this Joomla message system by using an URL parameter or something similar.